# Perl xml convert to word document?

Tags: xml, perl, docx

I am parsing xml document, i want to convert the xml content to word normal content without any tag.

example:
xml file:

```
<title>Introduction</title>
<sec>Welcome to this world</sec> 
<ref>Conclusion</ref>
```

Convert to word:

```
Introduction
Welcome to this world
Conclusion
```

please give any suggestion thanks in advance.

I have tried this code but it write the content what in xml file exactly.

```
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Word';
$Win32::OLE::Warn = 2; # Throw Errors, I'll catch them
use Cwd;
use File::Basename;
system 'cls';
#use strict;
use List::Uniq ':all';
use Sort::Versions;
my $xmlfile = 'D:\file.xml';
my $cnt = _open_utf8($xmlfile);
my $dir = dirname($xmlfile);
my $basename = basename($xmlfile);
my $wordsave = Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application', 'Quit') or die;
    $wordsave->{Visible} = 1;
    my $doc = $wordsave->Documents->Add();
    my $range = $doc->{Content};
    ### insert some text into the document
    $range->{Text} = $cnt;
    ### read text from the document and print to the console
    my $paras = $doc->Paragraphs;
    foreach my $para (in $paras) {
        print ">> " . $para->Range->{Text};
    }
    ### close the document and the application
    $doc->SaveAs(FileName => 'd:\temp.docx', FileFormat => wdFormatDocument);
    $doc->Close();
    $wordsave->Quit();
_save_utf8($dir.'\\out_'.$basename,$cnt);
```

Comment: You aren't parsing the XML though, are you? You're just reading it in. You'll need to (1) pick an XML module and (2) extract the text then (3) decide where you will put spacing and newlines.

Answer (score 1):

As Richard mentioned in comment you need to use a parser. You can try `XML::XPath`.

Check out [this article on perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=421936) which will teach you how to extract the data from XML file and create a Word file from extracted data.

Comment: Thank you very much. @Chankey Pathak and Richard Huxton